# Comparing two integers without logical, relational or bitwise operators

Tags: c, programming-challenge

I answered a question on SO today, however it did't receive any up-votes, so I want to know what's wrong with my code.

The requirement is to compare the input numbers(granted to be positive) **without logical, relational or bitwise operators**, and insert the corresponding comparison sign between them. For example:

```
input:  4 6
output: 4 < 6
input:  10 2
output: 10 > 2
input:  2 2
output: 2 = 2
```

Here is my posted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned a, b;
    scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);
    printf("%u ", a);
    char relationship[] = {'<', '=', '>'};
    putchar(relationship[!!(a/b) - !!(b/a) + 1]);
    printf(" %u", b);
    return 0;
}
```

That OP wants to know how to insert a comparison sign(`<`, `>`, `=`) between the two numbers. But my emphasis is on how to determine the relationship of the two numbers.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35532123/5399734 for the original question.

Comment: Isn't `!` considered a logical operator?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've improved this code to avoid `!` operators. See my posted code on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35533732/5399734

Comment: Should I post the improved code again by editing this question on code review?

Comment: The C spec has "... the **logical** negation operator **!**...". §6.5.3.3 5. Using ! does not  meet "without logical, relational or bitwise operators" and neither does [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120688/29485)

Comment: @sun qingyao Recommend against editing this code.  This is a review of your code - as is.  Changing the code invalidates the work done so far.  You could  post new code in a new question, adding links to this and that post for reference indicating the next one is a follow-on.  Maybe including ideas from the review(s) done here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a fine solution. Some minor suggestions:

- Instead of spelling out `relationship` as `{'<', '=', '>'}`, you could use simply `"<=>"`
- Instead of printing `a`, the relation and `b` in separate statements, it will be more readable to print in a single `printf`
- The expression `!!(a/b) - !!(b/a)` evaluates to -1, 0, 1, commonly returned by a `cmp` function. If you give the expression a name by putting it in a variable, that will ring a bell with many readers and make it easier to understand.

Something like this:

```
unsigned a, b;
scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);

int cmp = !!(a/b) - !!(b/a);
char relation = "<=>"[cmp + 1];
printf("%u %c %u\n", a, relation, b);
```

Comment: `!` is a logical operator per the C spec.

Comment: He's right, and perhaps we can use (_Bool). Please take a look at my updated code on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35533732/5399734 for details